Did Bernays change his mind?
Paul Bernays was a close collaborator of Hilbert's in their work on Formalism (finitism at the metamathematical level undergirding use of infinitary entities in the practice of mathematics).  Formalism is often understood to be a rival school to realism (or platonism?) in the philosophy of mathematics.  Decades later, Bernays expressed what seems like a moderate realist position in terms of the objectivity of mathematical "objects":

"there is no fundamental obstacle to attributing objectivity
sui generis to mathematical objects."

This is in his article

Bernays, Paul. Zum Symposium "uber die Grundlagen
der Mathematik.  Dialectica 25, no. 3/4,
Conclusions et r'eflexions finales du Symposium permanent de
math'ematiques (1971), 171--195.

As already mentioned, this is somewhat surprising, since Bernays collaborated with Hilbert on a Formalist programme.  There could be a variety of reasons for this:

Bernays changed his mind.  A user at a related question argues for this explanation.

Bernays' comment is actually compatible with his work on Formalism.

Bernays was over 80 at the time of this comment, and no longer in full command, etc.


Question. Are there any sources that would corroborate one of these explanations?

Hilbert himself changed his mind in late 1920s after Weyl's criticism of the "meaningless game of symbols" in Die heutige Erkenntnislage in der Mathematik (1925). Weyl analogized 'ideal' mathematics to theoretical physics, the analogy Hilbert went with, see Hallett, Physicalism, Reductionism & Hilbert:"Once new concepts or “ideal elements” or new theoretical terms have been accepted, then they exist in the sense in which any theoretical entities exist." So after 1928 even Hilbert could sign off on what Bernays said in 1971.

@Conifold, as you know there is a difference between "game formalism" and "mathematical formalism".  Is the phrase you are quoting from Hilbert or from Hallett?  The comment that appears there on page 239 is Hallett's, not Hilbert's :-)  Notice that the popular story is that Goedel's incompleteness in 1933 was a big blow to Hilbert's programme.  But if Hilbert already changed his mind in 1928, what was it a blow to exactly?

From Hallett, he surmises Hilbert's unpublished manuscripts on ideal elements, but the presentation changes even in publications. Hilbert of early 1920s can be read as a "game formalist", but not after 1928. The blow was to high hopes for finitary proofs of consistency, which were quite orthogonal to ontological status of mathematical objects.

Hallett provides a quotation from Hilbert on page 238 which seems at odds with the interpretation Hallett gives for Hilbert's position: "the totality of all real numbers, that is, the continuum, is not, according to the above characterised interpretation, the totality of all possible decimal expansions or the totality of all possible laws according to which a fundamental
series [i.e. Cauchy sequence] can proceed. ...

"... Rather it is a system of things whose
mutual relations are governed by the axioms set up, and for which all and only
those facts are true which can be derived from the axioms by means of a finite
number of logical inferences."  In my opinion, here Hilbert distances himself from a realist position (mentioned at the beginning of the passage), rather than adopting it as per Hallett. Hilbert's statement here is a good summary of a Formalist position that Robinson, for example, could subscribe to.  @Conifold

@Conifold, since you seem to have thought about these issues and feel that Hilbert '28 is compatible with Bernays '71, you could post this as an answer with references.  I am not sure I agree but it is an interesting perspective, so long as it is sourced.

The position is not realist, "exist in the sense in which" or "sui generis" is perfectly compatible with Hilbert's methodological instrumentalism or holistic pragmatism a la Quine. The passage simply means that we can abstract from said 'existence' or lack thereof "to describe the activity of our understanding, to make a protocol of the rules according to which our thinking actually proceeds." (1928). We only need more when we want to explain applicability of the 'game', why one is chosen over another, etc.

I haven't studied Quine carefully but it is not my impression that he would describe mathematical entities as "objects", nor that he would attribute to them "objectivity".  I agree with you that Quine was certainly no realist.  We seem both interested in this subject (though holding differing views), so why not post an answer :-)

Debates over answers take too much time here. But Quine has no problem analogizing physical and mathematical objects a la Weyl, and attributing 'existence' to them while calling them 'myths', etc:"Physical objects are postulated entities which round out, and simplify our account of the flux of experience, just, as the introduction of irrational numbers simplifies laws of arithmetic... The analogy between the myth of mathematics and the myth of physics is, in some additional and perhaps fortuitous ways, strikingly close."

@Conifold, if they are "myths" as per Quine, then they hardly possess "objectivity".  You can't have your cake and eat it, too (Actually I have always thought that the more logical version of this quip should be "you can't eat your cake and have it, too" :-)

Maybe relevant Paul Bernays, Sur le platonisme dans les mathématiques (1935): "We would say, roughly, that intuitionism is adapted to the theory of
numbers; the semiplatonistic method, which makes use of the idea of the
totality of integers but avoids quasi-combinatorial concepts, is adapted to
the arithmetic theory of functions, and the usual platonism is adequate for
the geometric theory of the continuum."

@MauroALLEGRANZA, Thanks!  I wasn't aware of that text.  If you read it, could you summarize the point or two?

Oh, but you can. "Myriad scattered sense events come to be associated with single so-called objects... a convenient myth, simpler than the literal truth and yet containing that literal truth as a scattered part." And so 'myths' exist sui generis as delegates of objective scatter. This line of thought goes back to Peirce, at least, and was eventually wrapped into indispensability argument for 'platonism' by Putnam, soon after Bernays's writing.

Such myths are apparently only "delegates" for objective chatter (I assume  you meant "chatter", not "scatter").  My impression was that Quine qualifies as a nominalist, not realist.  At any rate, I read more carefully what Hallett says there.  He quotes Hilbert as to the "reality" of atoms, and then admits that he only surmises that Hilbert must have felt the same way about mathematical entities.  Another attempt to eat the cake and have it, too :-) @Conifold

See Paul Bernays, Sur le platonisme dans les mathématiques (1935).
From the English translation [all emphasis mine]:

An example of this way of setting up a theory can be found in Hilbert’s axiomatization of geometry. If we compare Hilbert’s axiom system to Euclid’s,
ignoring the fact that the Greek geometer fails to include certain necessary
postulates, we notice that Euclid speaks of figures to be constructed whereas,
for Hilbert, system of points, straight lines, and planes exist from the outset.
Euclid postulates: One can join two points by a straight line; Hilbert states
the axiom: Given any two points, there exists a straight line on which both
are situated. “Exists” refers here to existence in the system of straight lines.
This example shows already that the tendency of which we are speaking
consists in viewing the objects as cut off from all links with the reflecting
subject. Since this tendency asserted itself especially in the philosophy of Plato,
allow me to call it “platonism.”


[...] The weakest of the “platonistic” assumptions introduced by arithmetic is
that of the totality of integers. [...] The platonistic conceptions of analysis and set theory have also been applied in modern theories of algebra and topology, where they have proved very fertile. This brief summary will suffice to characterize platonism and its application to mathematics. This application is so widespread that it is not an exaggeration to say that platonism reigns today in mathematics.


But on the other hand, we see that this tendency has been criticized in
principle since its first appearance and has given rise to many discussions.
This criticism was reinforced by the paradoxes discovered in set theory, even
though these antinomies refute only extreme platonism. We have set forth only a restricted platonism which does not claim to be more than, so to speak, an ideal projection of a domain of thought. But the matter has not rested there. Several mathematicians and philosophers interpret the methods of platonism in the sense of conceptual realism, postulating the existence of a world of ideal objects containing all the objects and relations of mathematics. It is this absolute platonism which has been shown untenable by the antinomies, particularly by those surrounding the Russell-Zermelo paradox. [...] We must therefore give up absolute platonism. But it must be observed that this is almost the only injunction which follows from the paradoxes.


[eliminating platonism] can be brought about [...] in two steps, corresponding to the two essential assumptions introduced by platonism. The first step is to replace by constructive concepts the concepts of a set, a sequence, or a function, which I have called quasi-combinatorial. [...] the second step of the elimination [...] consists in renouncing the idea of the totality of integers. This point of view was first defended by Kronecker and then developed systematically by Brouwer.

A discussion of Brouwer's Intuitionism follows. And then:

We would say, roughly, that intuitionism is adapted to the theory of
numbers; the semiplatonistic method, which makes use of the idea of the
totality of integers but avoids quasi-combinatorial concepts, is adapted to
the arithmetic theory of functions, and the usual platonism is adequate for
the geometric theory of the continuum. [...] As for this philosophic position, it seems to me that one must concede to Brouwer two essential points: first, that the concept of integer is of intuitive origin. In this respect nothing is changed by the investigations of the logicists, to which I shall return later. Second, one ought not to make arithmetic and geometry correspond in the manner in which Kant did. The concept of number is more elementary than the concepts of geometry. [...] In short, the point of view of intuitive evidence does not decide uniquely in favor of intuitionism.


On the other hand, for the theory of the continuum, given by analysis,
the intuitionist method seems rather artificial. The idea of the continuum is
a geometrical idea which analysis expresses in terms of arithmetic.
Is the intuitionist method of representing the continuum better adapted
to the idea of the continuum than the usual one? Weyl would have us believe this.


This suffices to show that the two tendencies, intuitionist and platonist,
are both necessary; they complement each other, and it would be doing
oneself violence to renounce one or the other.


It seems odd that Bernays quotes Hilbert concerning the "existence" of a line through two points, and then seems to infer from this that Hilbert was a platonist.  Euclid's axioms would apparently be unproblematic for Brouwer, also.  What do you make of this?

"game formalist" in the sense ridiculed by Frege wrt Heine and Thomae. Unfortunately, we have no Hilbert's "Tractatus on the Foundations of Mathematics, but see Controversy with Frege and Hilbert's Program:  Hilbert’s formalism was thus quite sophisticated: It avoided two crucial objections. ...

Missing the initial: "Hilbert was not a ..."

I am not sure what you are referring to.  Can you elaborate?

@MikhailKatz - well-known Hilbert's dictum "No one shall expel us from the paradise which Cantor has created for us" does not fit with the usual "formalist" stance (see e.g. your preferred A.Robinson).

Mauro, Robinson subscribes to this dictum as much as Hilbert does. Both view the use of infinitary entities (such as the infinities of the Cantorian paradise) as acceptable in the practice of mathematics. In the practice of metamathematics, on the other hand, it is preferable to use finitist reasoning, which usually means PRA. Note that by the results of reverse mathematics, Pi^0_2 sentences in WKL_0 are reducible to PRA, so the restriction is less stringent than it seems (corrected typo).
